# Summing the data for report

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one report and i want to display the how many leave he/she took in a month.

```
Report
--------
PL     1
SL     1
TL     0.5
ML     0
Total  3.5
No.Of Days 3
```

I have tried the below query but am not getting the sum of decimals...

```
select nvl(activity_type,'No.Of Days'),count(1)
from planner_activity
where tenant_id=500020
group by (activity_type)
order by 1;
```

In a month emploee will take a leave whether it is a Halfday(0.5) and full day(1). I need the report to display the count and sum of the days in a month.  If i took half day  holiday then the count is 1 and no.of days 0.5 days.
Please help me on this..

Many thanks for your help.

Sunitha.

Comment: So activity_type can be PL, SL, TL, etc. Is 'Total' also just an activity_type? Or do you want to have it calculated from something? And how do you get the number of days? Is it just activity_type NULL?

Comment: Hi,total is not activity type. It is the sum of the days. Thanks

Comment: PL + SL + TL + ML = 2.5. Total = 3.5. Number of days = 3. I don't see how these values are related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand the question.  And yet, I think this is the answer.  I think you want to use `rollup` with the `group by`:

```
select coalesce(activity_type, 'No.Of Days'), count(1)
from planner_activity
where tenant_id = 500020
group by rollup (activity_type)
order by (case when activity_type is null then 1 else 0 end), activity_type;
```

Comment: Hi,Thank you. In a month emploee will take a leave whether it is a Halfday(0.5) and full day(1). I need the report to display the count and sum of the days in a month.  If i took half day  holiday then the count is 1 and no.of days 0.5 days.